# Adjoint pairs, triplets and quadruplets

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Often we have adjoint pairs $(A, B)$ (meaning $A$ is left adjoint to $B$).
Sometimes we have adjoint triplets $(A,B,C)$ (meaning $A$ is left adjoint to $B$ and $B$ is left adjoint to $C$. No adjoint relation between $A$ and $C$ obviously, since they have the same source and target).

So the first question is: can we have quadruplets $(A,B,C,D)$ ? (meaning that $C$ is also left adjoint to $D$).

Second question:
It would be then possible that we have $(A,D)$ besides $(A,B)$. But I think not, because I think that it is not possible to have a functor $A$ with two different right adjoints, $B$ and $D$. Is this correct?

Comment: See this [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46877/natural-examples-of-sequences-of-adjoint-functors) for some good examples for the first question. For the second question: prove that the right adjoint of a functor is unique up to a unique isomorphism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, for every natural number $\ge 2$, there is a *maximal* string of adjoint functors of that length. Here's one construction: let $\mathbf{n}$ denote the poset category $\{ 0 < \ldots < n - 1 \}$. I claim there are functors (i.e. order-preserving maps)
\begin{align}
d_i & : \mathbf{n} \to \mathbf{n} + 1 & & 0 \le i \le n \newline
s_i & : \mathbf{n} + 1 \to \mathbf{n} & & 0 \le i \le n - 1
\end{align}
such that
$$d_n \dashv s_{n-1} \dashv d_{n-1} \dashv \cdots \dashv s_0 \dashv d_0$$
is a maximal string of adjoint functors. Moreover, if $\mathbf{C}$ is a category with a terminal object but no initial object, there are functors
\begin{align}
\partial_i & : [\mathbf{n} + 1, \mathbf{C}] \to [\mathbf{n}, \mathbf{C}] & & 0 \le i \le n \newline
\sigma_i & : [\mathbf{n}, \mathbf{C}] \to [\mathbf{n} + 1, \mathbf{C}] & & 0 \le i \le n
\end{align}
such that
$$\partial_0 \dashv \sigma_0 \dashv \cdots \dashv \partial_n \dashv \sigma_n$$
is a maximal string of adjoint functors. (Here $[\mathbf{D}, \mathbf{C}]$ denotes the category of all functors $\mathbf{D} \to \mathbf{C}$.)

It is also not hard to find an infinite string of adjoint functors: for example, 
$$\cdots \dashv \textrm{id} \dashv \textrm{id} \dashv \textrm{id} \dashv \cdots$$
is such a string, though a little degenerate.

As for your second question, recall that adjoints are unique up to unique natural isomorphism, i.e. if $F \dashv G$ and $F \dashv G'$, then there is a unique natural isomorphism $G \cong G'$ which interacts nicely with the unit and counit of the adjunction.

Comment: There's something odd with the first example: you define $s_i$ with $0\leq i \leq n-1$ but then in the chain below you use $s_n$. Also, wouldn't such a chain prove only that there is a maximal string of adjoint functors of odd length? (As it stands, the chain has length $2n+1$)

Comment: @Bruno: $\sigma_n$ is not defined using $s_n$ (since it doesn't exist) and is quite different from the rest of them. If $\mathbf{C}$ has an initial object then there's also a $\sigma_{-1}$. Unless you are deliberately excluding posets from your definition of "category", the very first string of adjoints is a string of even length.

Comment: I never said anything about $\sigma_n$, I'm only talking about the first example (before the "moreover"): the second functor in the chain is $s_n$.

Comment: @Bruno: Sorry, that's a typo. It's $s_{n-1}$, as the pattern suggests.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. Could you please elaborate a bit on the examples? I've found that the first maps are called coface and codegeneracy maps, and they are the obvious injections and surjections. Is the second example a variation on the face/degeneracy maps? Can't you tweak the coface/codegeneracy maps you have above? FWIW, I'm not familiar at all with simplicial theory.

Comment: The inner adjoints of the second example are induced by the face and degeneracy maps via precomposition. The outermost ones are a little different.