# Sequences or 'chains' of adjoint functors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Suppose we have (some categories and some functors such that) $F_1$ is left adjoint to $G_1$, $G_1$ left adjoint to $F_2$, $F_2$ left adjoint to $G_2$.
Will $F_1$ then be equal to $F_2$ (and $G_1$ to $G_2$)? 
Or can there exist arbitrarily long 'chains' of adjoint functors that do not trivialize?

Comment: @ZhenLin That's not an exact duplicate. The other question essentially asks whether a right adjoint can have a right adjoint itself at all. This question asks an example where this new adjoint is different from the starting functor. (For example, you answer $\dots \dashv id \dashv id \dashv \dots$ wouldn't work at all here).

Comment: I also mention that there are arbitrarily long finite strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, such infinite chains indeed exist.

Consider an additive category ${\mathscr A}$, its category of ${\mathbb Z}$-graded chain complexes $\text{Ch}({\mathscr A})$ and the associated forgetful functor ${\mathcal V}: \text{Ch}({\mathscr A})\to{\mathscr A}^{\mathbb Z}$. A left adjoint ${\mathcal L}: {\mathscr A}^{\mathbb Z}\to\text{Ch}({\mathscr A})$ to ${\mathcal V}$ is given by sending some $X_{\ast}\in\text{Obj}({\mathscr A}^{\mathbb Z})$ to the chain complex ${\mathcal L}(X) := \Sigma^{-1}\text{Cone}((X_{\ast},0)\xrightarrow{\text{id}} (X_{\ast},0))$. In words, we first equip $X_{\ast}$ with the trivial differential and then form the cone over it. Explicitly,
$${\mathcal L}(X)\quad\ \equiv\quad ...\to X_{n-1}\oplus X_{n}\xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \text{id} \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}} X_{n}\oplus X_{n+1}\to ...,$$
where $X_{n-1}\oplus X_{n}$ sits in cohomological degree $n$. 
Next, a right adjoint ${\mathcal R}$ to ${\mathcal V}$ is given by $${\mathcal R}(X) := \Sigma\ {\mathcal L}(X)\quad\equiv\quad ...\to X_n\oplus X_{n+1}\xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \text{id} \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}} X_{n+1}\oplus X_{n+2}\to ...$$
where now $X_n\oplus X_{n+1}$ sits in cohomological degree $n$.

Hence we obtain the infinite chain of adjunctions

$$...\dashv {\mathcal L}\dashv {\mathcal V}\dashv {\mathcal R}\equiv\Sigma{\mathcal L}\dashv {\mathcal V}\Sigma^{-1}\dashv \Sigma {\mathcal R}\equiv\Sigma^2{\mathcal L}\dashv ...$$

*Addendum* The above example is rather ring-theoretical than homological: For ${\mathscr A} := k\text{-Vect}$ for a field $k$, it is essentially the observation that the ${\mathbb Z}$-graded algebra $k[x]/(x^2)$ is *graded Frobenius*. For an ordinary finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over $k$, being Frobenius implies that induction and coinduction from the base field are isomorphic as functors $k\text{-Vect}\to A\text{-Mod}$, but for graded Frobenius algebras this is only true up to shift by the *Gorenstein parameter* of the algebra - which is $1$ in the above case. Hence, graded Frobenius algebras provide many examples of infinite non-periodic chains of adjunctions, but they all have the property that they are periodic up to twisting by an automorphism.

Interestingly, the infinite version of Zhen's example from [Adjoint pairs, triplets and quadruplets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92023/adjoint-pairs-triplets-and-quadruplets) also exhibits this periodicity up to twisting by automorphisms: consider the poset $({\mathbb Z},\leq)$ as a category and look at the following order preserving functions / functors $({\mathbb Z},\leq)\to({\mathbb Z},\leq)$: $$\iota_n: {\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb Z},\quad \iota_n(k) := \begin{cases} k & \text{ if } k\leq n\\ k+1 & \text{ if }k>n\end{cases},\\
\pi_n: {\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb Z},\quad \pi_n(k) := \begin{cases} k & \text{ if } k\leq n\\ k-1 & \text{ if }k>n\end{cases}.$$
Then we have $$...\dashv \iota_n\dashv \pi_n\dashv \iota_{n-1}\dashv \pi_{n-1}\dashv ...,$$
but again $\pi_n \cong \Sigma^n \pi_0\Sigma^{-n}$ where $\Sigma : {\mathbb Z}\to {\mathbb Z}$ is the successor automorphism.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's in fact possible for $F_1$ to be not isomorphic from $F_2$ (and this automatically implies $G_1 \not\cong G_2$, because left adjoints are unique up to isomorphism and $F_1 \dashv G_1$, $F_2 \dashv G_2$). The chain can even go on indefinitely in both directions.

Here's an example. Let $i : \mathsf{A} \to \mathsf{B}$ be a functor, and let $i^* : \mathsf{C}^\mathsf{B} \to \mathsf{C}^\mathsf{A}$ be the restriction functor. Assume everything is nice so that the [Kan extensions](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension) exist. Then you have
$$\operatorname{Lan}_i \dashv i^* \dashv \operatorname{Ran}_i$$
but in general left and right Kan extensions are rarely isomorphic. By using categories of sheaves it's possible to work out an example where either $\operatorname{Ran}_i$ has a right adjoint or $\operatorname{Lan}_i$ has a left adjoint.